# A regular expression to clean up XML

Tags: xml, regex, posix

I have to deal with XML data that sometimes contains the unescaped ampersand and I can't get the producer to either escape it to & or put it into a CDATA section.

Now I'm looking for a regular expression to replace & with & amp; if its not part of an entity. Something like this: &(?!(amp|apos|quot|lt|gt);)

Unfortunately, my programming environment only support "extended POSIX 1003.2 regular expressions" (see http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/regex.7.html) which seem to lack the not operator "!" needed here.

Any ideas how to craft the necessary regular expression ?

Comment: the correct "XML-ish" response would be to run it through a validator, and reject as "not well formed XML". Its a shame the designers of XML didn't allow for the fact that in the real world we sometimes have to put up with bad input and work with it.

Comment: @Spudley: I actually do run the XML file through a validator. Thats how I noticed the malformed part. Unfortunately its a Microsoft product producing the invalid XML and to them "standard" seems to mean "optional".

Comment: hehe. Microsoft eh? That figures. (going further off topic, since the commercial support is the reason management often give for buying Microsoft, I wonder if MS would be prepared to fix it for you? Of course not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lateral thinking: Replace all `&` with `&amp` then replace all `&amp;apos` (etc) with `&apos` (for example)? You can use  a group to capture the part to be put back - `&amp;(apos)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for something matching a negative regex you could search for something NOT matching a positive regex, something like:

```
! ... &(?(amp|apos|quot|lt|gt);)
```

I did no read the whole page you linked, but am pretty sure it should be possible.